# I need help generating a custom URL based on the user ID

Tags: wordpress

I need help on how generate a unique URL based on a users ID for example

```
var htmlstring = "https://www.google.com" + "?" + <?php get_userdata( $userid ); ?>
```

This is the JS I have that creates a hyperlink in the html:

```
Click <script type="text/javascript">
function zs_open_window(url, height, width){var leftPos = 0;var topPos = 0;if(screen){leftPos = (screen.width - width) / 2;topPos = (screen.height - height) / 2;window.open(url, null, 'width='+width+',height='+height+',left='+leftPos+',top='+topPos+', toolbar=0, location=0, status=1, scrollbars=1, resizable=1');}}</script><a href="https://survey.zohopublic.com/zs/NbB3YM" title="" target="_blank" onclick="zs_open_window(this.href, 648, 700); return false;" rel="noopener noreferrer">HERE</a>
```

I need to get the Wordpress username as a JS variable so I can modify the href to be href="https://survey.zohopublic.com/zs/NbB3YM?USERNAME".

I know how to modify the href, I just don't know how push a username into a JS variable?

Ben

Comment: Ben, there isn't enough info here. What will be happening when a user visits the unique url? Do you want to mask the user id? What part are you having trouble with? Are you having an issue getting the site url? Are you just having trouble doing this in JS instead of PHP?

Comment: wp_localize_script is a WordPress function that can be used to send your PHP data to your javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could setup a global variable on all pages that holds that information by adding this to your `header.php` file just above the `<?php wp_head(); ?>` line.

```
<?php
    // Gets the current user.
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    // Checks if the visitor is logged in.
    if ( $current_user->ID !== 0 ) {
    // Output JS
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var htmlstring = "https://survey.zohopublic.com/zs/NbB3YM?username=<?php echo $current_user->user_login ?>";
    </script>

<?php
    } // End if
?>
```

You can then use `htmlstring` in any of your other JS functions or code. I also added the `username=` parameter as you might need that so you can pass it to something else. If you don't, just remove it.

Comment: Thanks @disinfor that worked perfectly I complemented it giving the <a> an ID then used the DOM.href to update the URL.